# Cannot write basic useQuery statement in typescript without type error

Tags: typescript, react-query

Trying to write a basic `useQuery` statement in typescript, to fetch some data...

For this, I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bhairabpatra.iitd/usequery-hook-in-react-b06ef604ea46), which is similar to many others.

I wrote the following simple code, based on the tutorial:

```js
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'

const SomesComponent = () => {
  const someApi = useSomeApi()

  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const response = await someApi.getAll()
    return response?.data
  }

  const { data } = useQuery('todos' /*<- error here */, () => fetchProducts())

  // ...
```

however, this is giving me a typescript error on vscode:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(options: UndefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UndefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options: DefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): DefinedUseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(options: UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

[It seems they changed the way to pass arguments to `useQuery` on v4](https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/overview), and all the docs online show the way for v3 (including the React Query Homepage, by default, shows the v3 way)...

The new way (v4 and v5) is:

```js
function Example() {
  const { isPending, error, data } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['repoData'],
    queryFn: () =>
      fetch('https://api.github.com/repos/TanStack/query').then((res) =>
        res.json(),
      ),
  })
```